# How to find printer ip address in the same lan or wifi network?

Tags: java, android, networking, printing

Actually, i need to print a document without print manager in android. So i would able to get all ip address in the same wifi network. But i am unable to find which one is printer ip address. So please update any one if you know.

Comment: @RaghavPai Did you understand my question? I am unable to see difference between system and printer ip address.

Comment: i am sorry fr d confusion

Answer (score 2):

You can use the framework's [Network Service Discovery](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). Look for service type: "_ipp._tcp".

Comment: Thanks alot! @Nonos

Comment: do you know how to find other devices using Network Service Discovery?

Comment: Services and port numbers are defined by IANA: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml. The service type is in the format “_<protocol>._<transportLayer>”