# Android printing without showing document

Tags: java, android

How can I print from android phone or tablet without showing the document ?

This is what i tried :

```
List<PrinterId> ids=new ArrayList<PrinterId>();
PrinterId id=printService.generatePrinterId(info.getNickname());
ids.add(id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chetan, Android would not allow to print like this. First you should find the ip in the network using, [Network Service Discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760465/how-to-find-printer-ip-address-in-the-same-lan-or-wifi-network).

Please refer more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760465/how-to-find-printer-ip-address-in-the-same-lan-or-wifi-network)